# How to overcome those prettier errors?

Tags: prettier

After commenting out and uncommenting some lines in a YML file, I can't get my project pushed to our Gitlab anymore due to those prettier errors. To be precise, the commented out block is the server 8080 and uncommented block is the server 443.

```
✖ prettier --write:
[error] src/main/resources/config/application-prod.yml: SyntaxError: All collection items must start at the same column (16:1)
[error]        14 | # ===================================================================
[error]        15 |
[error] >    16 | logging:
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    17 |      level:
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    18 |          ROOT: INFO
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    19 |          tech.jhipster: INFO
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    20 |          com.abc.myapp: INFO
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    21 |
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    22 | management:
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    23 |      metrics:
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    24 |          export:
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    25 |              prometheus:
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
[error] >    26 |                  enabled: false
[error]              | ^^^^^^^^
...
[error] > 129 |
[error]              | ^
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

The error message says

```
 All collection items must start at the same column (16:1)
```

I didn't change those lines at all. After making a comparison of the before and after editing versions of the same file in an IDE, I don't see any changes on those lines say line 16.

How to overcome this problem?

Here is the original file:

```
# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration for the "prod" profile.
#
# This configuration overrides the application.yml file.
#
# More information on profiles:  https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/
# More information on configuration properties: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
#   ===================================================================

# ===================================================================
# Standard Spring Boot properties.
# Full reference is available at:
# http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
# ===================================================================

logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    tech.jhipster: INFO
    com.abc.myapp: INFO

management:
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: false

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: false
    livereload:
      enabled: false
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp
    username: myapp
    password:
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
  jpa:
    database-platform: tech.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL10Dialect
  # Replace by 'prod, faker' to add the faker context and have sample data loaded in production
  liquibase:
    contexts: prod
  thymeleaf:
    cache: true
 security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: https://xyz.abc.com/
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: 78368cea7-17f90-439b-ac0f8-8a3296b300a50a
            client-secret: gto_ha769wcw4tafye7jrtljcmfe0vrk7k2r7yvaz38rpbkzo63o8s8tggn2pq
            scope: openid,profile,email,offline_access

# ===================================================================
# To enable TLS in production, generate a certificate using:
# keytool -genkey -alias myapp -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
#
# You can also use Let's Encrypt:
# https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm
#
# Then, modify the server.ssl properties so your "server" configuration looks like:

server:
  port: 443
  SSL:
    key-store: classpath:/home/ec12-user/docker/wrwvw/webapp-docker
    key-store-password: sf8*#l9
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: myapp
    # The ciphers suite enforce the security by deactivating some old and deprecated SSL cipher, this list was tested against SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)
    ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
# ===================================================================
# server:
#  port: 8080
#  shutdown: graceful # see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-graceful-shutdown
#  compression:
#    enabled: true
#    mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript,application/json,image/svg+xml
# min-response-size: 1024

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
  HTTP:
    cache: # Used by the CachingHttpHeadersFilter
      timeToLiveInDays: 1461
  cache: # Cache configuration
    ehcache: # Ehcache configuration
      time-to-live-seconds: 3600 # By default objects stay 1 hour in the cache
      max-entries: 1000 # Number of objects in each cache entry
  logging:
    use-json-format: false # By default, logs are not in Json format
    logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
      enabled: false
      host: localhost
      port: 5000
      queue-size: 512
# ===================================================================
# Application specific properties
# Add your own application properties here, see the ApplicationProperties class
# to have type-safe configuration, like in the JHipsterProperties above
#
# More documentation is available at:
# https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

# application:
```

Comment: please add the data source file listing, up to line 26, if possible

Comment: Get the file posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having similar issues with parsing errors with husky when trying to do a git commit. I "solved" it following this [answer](https://programmerah.com/error-husky-%EF%BC%9E-pre-commit-node-%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bv10-16-3-is-reported-when-git-commit-is-submitted-28101/) which says that you need to add a `--no-verify` flag:

`git commit -m "message for the commit" --no-verify`

**Disclaimer:** this overcomes the prettier errors but does not solve it. Be sure to check that your code works properly and follows the respective code guidelines before overpassing it. After you succesfully have done that, you will not need to use the `--no-verify` again unless you modify that file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience on the subject. I modify the package.json file by removing yml from the prettier format check to push my code in. Like yours, that doesn't really solve the problem. I still don't understand why commenting and uncommenting some lines in a yaml file led to the formatting error.

Answer (score 1):

The checkmarked answer is not great advice, in my opinion. `--no-verify` will bypass all pre-commit checks. If you're having issues with files that shouldn't be parsed on a pre-commit you need to modify the ignore file of your parser.

In this case it would be adding or modifying the .prettierignore file.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Or if you need to ignore a range of code then comment appropriately to allow that range to be ignored:

https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#range-ignore

https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#yaml

If this is a situation where your code is not working due to a styling issue consider running `prettier write <FILE>` in your console.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html